# Opening a new tab on select change - only works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a regular `select` element:

```
<div id="standings-listing">
    <select>
        <option value="0">please select</option>
        <option value="1">one</option>
        <option value="2">two</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

My client, despite my attempts to convince them otherwise, wants the site to open a page in a new tab every time a user changes the value of the element.

```
$('#standings-listing').on('change', 'select', function(){
        if($(this).val() > 0)
            $('<a href="/league/standings/'+$(this).val()+'" target="blank"></a>')[0].click();
    });
```

The above hacky lump of code works in Chrome, but in Firefox it doesn't, and apparently neither does it work on most phone browsers. Big surprise.

Anyway, I have confirmed that the event itself fires, so opening the new tab is where the problem lies. For example, this works the same in all browsers:

```
$('#standings-listing').on('change', 'select', function(){
        console.log('My boss wants me to hack the internet');
    });
```

Is there a way to make this work cross-browser or should I just go back to trying to convince them not to try this at all?

EDIT: when I use window.open(url, '_blank') instead of creating a link, I get this:

[image]

Comment: _"A valid browsing context name or keyword is any string that is either a valid browsing context name or that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for one of: `_blank`, `_self`, `_parent`, or `_top`"_ ([Source](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#auxiliary-browsing-context))

Comment: What's wrong with using `window.open()`?? I can't work out why you created a hyperlink object for this

Comment: @ADyson I forgot to explain that. See my edit at the end of the question please.

Comment: @jovan - The popup blocker's going to get involved with an auto-clicked link, too.

Comment: @Andreas I see, I mistyped "_blank". But when I fix that, the same problem remains (using both methods I tried).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a use case for `window.open`.¹ But the reason it doesn't work consistently cross-browser is twofold:

1. On some browsers (such as Firefox), the link must be in the document for clicking it programmatically to work. For instance, if you change your code to:

   ```
   $('#standings-listing').on('change', 'select', function(){
       if($(this).val() > 0) {
           var link = $('<a href="/league/standings/'+$(this).val()+'" target="blank"></a>');
           link.appendTo(document.body);
           link[0].click();
           link.remove();
       }
   });
   ```

   ...it works on Firefox (by "works" I mean it triggers Firefox's popup blocker; the user can then choose to allow the popup, just once or from that point forward).
2. If you want a new window each time, the target should be `_blank`, not `blank`. The latter is a named target that will get reused. The former is the special flag saying "a new blank window."

Hopefully the fact the popup blocker gets involved will deter the client.

---

¹ You've updated the question to say the reason you're using this rather than `window.open` is that `window.open` triggers the popup blocker. So you can switch to using `window.open` now that you know it'll get triggered either way. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.open()` instead

```
$('#standings-listing').on('change', 'select', function(){
    if($(this).val() > 0)
        var url = "/league/standings/"+$(this).val();
        window.open(url);
    }
});
```